# How to retrieve value from Dict

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm getting JSON format data from the server, then I convert the data format to the [String:Any].

```
JSON--> {
          integer = 1;
          length = "<null>";
           object =     (
           "692b663b-b7d5-43-287ddaadc2ff"
            );
          string = "SANJEEV TREHAN";
        }
```

Here is the code:

```
    if let data = data{
            do{
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {

                    if let integer = json["integer"] as? Int {
                         DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if integer == 1{
                            //retrieve data here
                            print(json)

                        }
                        else{
                           print("alert")
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    else{
                        print("no name")
                    }
                }
```

after converting the data as [String: Any]:

```
json = `["length": <null>, "integer": 1, "string": SANJEEV TREHAN, "object": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x2806acb10>(
692b663b-b7d5-43d5-daadc2ff) ]`
```

I want to retrieve the object key value from the `json` variable.

The data I want only is `692b663b-b7d54a-7dd-aadc2ff` as the String

I tried many things but not getting the data which format I want.

Comment: What are the "many things" that you tried?

Comment: can you share the json here?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Swift, why not use `Codable` types instead? They're much easier to use and you don't have to do weird casting or testing everywhere.

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
  let length: Int?
  let integer: Int
  let string: String
  let object: SomeObject
}

struct SomeObject: Codable {
  let uuid: UUID
}

do {
  let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Now you can now ask for the fields directly.

```swift
print(response.object.uuid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your object key is an array of string. Here is how you can get the value.

```
if let yourObject = json["object"] as? [String] {
  if yourObject.count != 0 { 
    yourObjectValue = yourObject[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response and tell me one thing what technologies is better to store the `token`  in the IOS App until the app data is not cleared

Comment: You can user UserDefaults. Please mark the answer correct if it worked. :)

Comment: If you want to store it in encrypted format to make it secure, you can use KeychainSwift wrapper. https://cocoapods.org/pods/KeychainSwift

Comment: keychainSwift will store the data permanently. I want to delete the data from the store when the app will uninstall. Is Userdefaults is good for this??